# How to use Google Fitness API in xamarin forms PCL?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-api, xamarin.android, google-fit

Im very new to Xamarin forms and mobile programming, so bear with me. Im doing a project where i need to show users' daily number of steps. Hence i need to use Google Fitness API but as ive seen so far, my class has to extend AppCompactActivity when trying to create GoogleApiClient. Initially i thought id create an interface in PCL, then implement it in android project(and use Fitness API there) but im not sure how to do that since it needs to extend an activity. Im kinda lost as to what happens if i start activity from android project. I dont want to start activity, just need to get History Data and return it to PCL shared code to display it there.
Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Skip the Android SDK and Use the HTTPS/Rest API directly : https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/

Comment: is there no other way to get step count from android?

Comment: ? Are you talking about getting the raw sensor data, or the aggregate steps taken per day?

Comment: My end goal is to get current daily steps taken and show it on the screen with as little code as possible. I want to avoid creating a service and  so i was wondering if android already has features i could access. Does not android store step counts out of the box? or do i have to store them first and then retrieve them with Fitness API?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: [Here is a article about step count in Android](http://www.gadgetsaint.com/android/create-pedometer-step-counter-android/#.WkC-59-WaUk).